# scrapy-splash returns no javascript version of page

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I'm using scrapy-splash via docker to access this page: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX/options?p=NFLX

The script works (sort of!), however, the page that's returned has `class="NoJs chrome featurephone"` specified and doesn't contain all of the fields I want to extract.

These are my settings:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for yahoo_options project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = 'yahoo_options'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['yahoo_options.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'yahoo_options.spiders'

# ScrapySplash settings
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

# set custom dupfilter class for Splash
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'

# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Chrome/79.0.3945.123 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
#ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

This is my script:

```
class yahoo_optionsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yahoo_options'
    consent_url = 
    start_urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NFLX/options?p=NFLX']

    def parse(self, response):
        # get list of contract dates
        #options_dates = response.css('div.drop-down-selector > select > option::text').extract()

        print(response.text)
```

Initially, I'd like to extract the option expiry dates from the dropdown menu which isn't available in the none JS version of the page.

I tried changing the `USER_AGENT` from the scrapy default to the one detailed in the settings above. I also tried switching IP addresses with a VPN in an attempt to obfuscate that the request was coming from a docker instance.

I've managed to achieve what I'm aiming for using `HTMLSession()` from  `requests_html` and wanted to find out if the same was possible with Scrapy + Splash.

I sense this could be due to the site identifying the request as a bot. Any suggestions on how I can get around this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Running into a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution with scrapy + splash?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I don't remember and the project was deleted from an old laptop. One option would be to use Selenium/Playwright instead of Splash.